# libgd not installed in php:5.6-cli docker

Tags: php, docker, gd, dockerfile, php-extension

I have a project inside a container and Im trying to use the gd lib for image create.

I do inside the bash of the container this command:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

Nothing changes after restart and execute `php -m`

What should I do?

Edit:

I added to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

I execute docker build -t [name]

But when I execute the bash and type : `php -m`

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```

Comment: What do you mean by `execute the bash`? Can you please state exactly where and how you try to run `php -m`?

Comment: @k0pernikus  `sudo docker exec -ti name bash` inside i use `php -m`

Comment: I assume that you don't run the newly created image but an an outdated container. I have updated my answer for you to see that the image has the proper module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't install gd manually. There's the `docker-php-ext-install` for that.

Inside the dockerfile, add:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

There is a bit of an annoyance with `docker-php-ext-install` that you have to figure out manually what dependencies you'll need. They don't resolve automatically. Due to this, the command will crash on its own, with:

```
configure: error: png.h not found.
```

If you look for the error, you will realize that you need `libpng-dev`.

Hence finally, the whole `Dockerfile` should look something like this:

```
FROM php:5.6-cli
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd > /dev/null
```

docker-php-ext-install is a bit verbose in its output, hence I like to pipe its output to `/dev/null`. Errors and warnings will still be printed.

You can check that the image has the proper extension by running the image:

```
docker build -t php-gd .
docker run php-gd /bin/bash -c "php -m | grep gd"
```

Will print:

```
gd
```

---

Same within a docker-compose stack:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
gd-example:
    build: .
    tty: true

docker-compose up --build -d
docker ps // to find container's name. You may also set in the config
docker exec -it docker_gd-example_1 php -m | grep gd
```

---

Two sidenotes:

1. From your question is was not clear if you built your container and then run `apt-get install php5-gd` from it. If so, then that would only instal php5-gd within that container and everytime you recreate it, it will be gone. Always add stuff to a container from within the `Dockerfile`.
2. Give `php:7.1-cli` a try. Do you really need to support php 5.6? ;)

Comment: When I execute your command print gd. but when I do docker-compose -p name restart of all my containers, when I go inside one and I type `php -m | grep gd` there is nothing :/

Comment: @devtreat Did you rebuild the containers via `docker-compose build`?